# Fabric gateway doesn't seem to use my env.user setting

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

This is really killing me, and it's probably something super easy/stupid.

I recently picked up a fabric project that was half completed and am finishing fleshing it out, with no previous experience with fabric. The first thing I'm trying to do is setting up gateway connections so I don't have to run fab from 1 of 4 different gateway machines for each environment we deploy to.

So, the setup is...

```
'base' --> 'dev_gateway' --> 'dev_environment'

'base' --> 'qa_gateway' --> 'qa_environment'

'base' --> 'prod_gateway' --> 'prod_environment'
```

Now, in my fabfile.py, I set env.user to the user that runs the applications in each dev, qa, and prod environments (the same user across all envs). I then set env.gateway to the user@gateway for each of the 4 gateways (different user for each gateway) depending on which environment is targeted.

I now get this error for all commands that run on target machines:

```
Fatal error: Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host: server1), but input would be ambiguous in parallel mode
```

SSH keys are in place and a command like this does work without prompting for a password:

```
ssh qa_gateway_user@qa_gateway "ssh common_user@qa_env_server \"echo TEST\""
```

Also, when I run my fab command with --show=debug, it shows that the gateway user is correct. It won't output anything for me on a target host, even a simple run('echo TEST') or run('uname -n') to verify the correct user is being picked up.

Anyone have any ideas? It's like fabric is ignoring my env.user because I'm using a gateway. If I don't set a gateway and run the fab commands from the gateway boxes themselves, there's no issue.

Thanks in advance, this is driving me nuts.

Comment: Does it work in serial mode? (just to make sure it's a parrallel mode thing)

Comment: The problem is hard to identify as you do not show any code. Do you define env.user in a task methode and run a sudo or run in the same methode?